# Difference in Impulse Responses - Bayesian analysis

Tags: time-series, bayesian, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I have estimated a time-varying parameter vector auto-regressive model (TVP-VAR) as in Primiceri. (2005). [Time Varying Structural Vector Autoregressions and
Monetary Policy](http://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~gep575/tvsvar_final_july_04.pdf). I then proceed to compute impulse responses as I would for a constant parameter model i.e. I compute the impulse responses for each time period but when calculating them I disregard the fact that the coefficients change (see Koop and Korobilis. (2009). [Bayesian Multivariate Time Series Methods for Empirical Macroeconomics](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/gary.koop/koop_korobilis_Foundations_and_Trends_2010.pdf) , p. 321, footnote 3 where they mention this and show the IRF's). Note that for each period one calculates the distribution of impulse responses for each period and then takes the median or similar together with credible interval to present in a graph.

I now want to compare the impulse responses for, say 1981:Q1 and 2011Q:3 to see if they differ.

My question is how to go about doing this. Should I:

**(a)**
Calculate the median impulse responses from the distribution of impulse responses for 1981:Q1 and 2011Q:3 (Median impulse response for 1981: $IRF1981$ and median impulse response for 2011: $IRF2011$) together with credible intervals. Then simply calculate: $IRF1981-IRF2011$ and the same for thecredible intervals and then plot these.

**(b)**
Calculate the difference between the distributions of impulse responses ($Dist1981-Dist2011 = Dist_{Difference}$) and then calculate the median and credible intervals for $Dist_{Difference}$ and plot these?

I can add a graph for both approaches here in case that helps. I think that approach **(b)** is correct but would like some reassurance on this.